# Did something interfere with Raina using her new powers?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, marvel, avengers-age-of-ultron, agents-of-shield

In the last episode S02E19 of *Marvel's Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D.*,

> Raina had vision of events that would play out in *Avengers: Age of Ultron*, including an image of Loki's scepter.

In response, she had an *extremely* bad reaction, much worse than her previous uses of her power. Was this just a natural reaction? Was she simply overwhelmed with what she now believed was going to happen? Or, was there something interfering with her, specifically,

> did the Mind Stone inside the scepter disrupt her vision?

Comment: What makes you think she had a stroke?

Comment: @Omegacron Don't take the word literally. If the word is really that much confusing, feel free to replace.

Comment: I don't think she had a stroke. She seemed just fearful of the future by the end of that scene.

Comment: @SS-3.1415926535897932384626433 it's not an insignificant word in the context. if it's a stroke, that's a lot more than just interfering, that's downright *injuring*, and possibly killing her.

Comment: Could you please stop making up completely random things that are totally unanswerable just to farm rep? That would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

In the scene you mention, **there is no evidence that anything external is affecting Raina**. Rather, she appears to simply be reacting to the vision itself - a glimpse of not only a beautiful (yet dangerous) scepter, but also scenes of death & destruction which show an army of metal men destroying our world, which is a rather obvious reference to

> Ultron and his drones from [**Avengers: Age of Ultron**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avengers:_Age_of_Ultron).

Also, keep in mind that these powers are still pretty new - it's quite likely that Raina is still processing the fact that her dreams will come true. On top of that, this is the first time she has ever received a vision while awake, which would be pretty shocking.

Comment: Do you think a murderer would be affected like an innocent kid?

Comment: @SS-3.1415926535897932384626433 not sure what you mean. Raina may not be innocent, but she's not exactly a hardened killer either.